# Finding "types" (reporter/command, and different contexts) of Procedures

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to extract, and sort, a list of all procedures in a model. Basically I want only the procedures that can be run in the Observer context, and only commands, not reporters. Workspaces have a `.getProcedures():Map<String, Procedure>` method and I am accessing the Procedure objects from that.

This leads me to two related questions: 1. Is there a way for me to find out if a `Procedure` object is a reporter or a command? The NetLogo desktop version seems to be able to make this distinction, so I think the answer might be yes. And 2. is there a way for me to find out what the Context of a procedure is, i.e. whether it is a patch/turtle/link procedure or an observer procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/scaladoc/org/nlogo/nvm/Procedure.html shows that Procedure has a syntax method returning an `api.Syntax` object. The methods you need are there, namely `ret` (which will be `Syntax.VoidType` or `Syntax.WildcardType` according to whether it is a command or reporter procedure) and `agentClassString` (which might be e.g. "OTPL").

Oh actually I see also now that the first constructor parameter to Procedure is `Type tyype` (the extra y is because `type` is a keyword in Scala), so for the first part of your question, you could equally well check that and see whether it is `COMMAND` or `REPORTER`. There probably isn't any good reason the information is redundantly stored.